# how to pass multiple values (arrays) through ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**how to pass arrays through ajax PHP**

Hi all  how to get multiple values into an array  then how to pass arrays through ajax to PHP

**HTML CODE**

```
 <input type='hidden' value='Jhon' class='pnm name' id='name-1'>
 <input type='hidden' value='jamma' class='pnm name' id='name-2'>
 <input type='hidden' value='saki' class='pnm name' id='name-3'>

 <input type='hidden' value='Jhon' class='pnm id' id='id-1'>
 <input type='hidden' value='jamma'class='pnm id' id='id-2'>
 <input type='hidden' value='saki' class='pnm id' id='id-3'>
   <input type='button' class='tn' value='send'>
```

**AJAX CODE**

```
  $(".tn").click(function(){
  var trid[]=$('.id').val();
    var name[]=$('.name').val();

      $.post("/free/",
    {trid:trid, name:name},
   function(data){
    alert(data);
     });

      });
   });
```

Please Help me how to pass two arrays in a single request through ajax, Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to pass all variables to AJAX, use [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

```
var data = $('#form_id').serialize();
```

Comment: ok, ill try this and what about Inside Php